# can I use extern "C" { headerfile of c }

Tags: c++, c, linkage

Instead of writing each function in " `extern "C" {}` ", can I write entire header file inside that block.

```
extern "C"
{
  #include "myCfile.h" 
}
```

I have tried this but Its not working at all, why it is not working ?
if we have to use 100 C functions in a c++ project, do we need provide all the functions in a
extern block, is there any other simple way ?

Ex:

```
extern "C"
{
 void fun1();
 void fun2();
 void fun3();
 void fun4();
 void fun5();
 .
 .
 .
 .
 fun100();
}
```

Is there any other simple way, like `extern "C" {  myCfunctions.h  }` ???

Comment: "Not working"? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: `#include` simply includes the specified header at the location of the `#include`. Whether it's valid depends on what `"myCfile.h"` contains. All that can be said without further info is that your approach is uncommon.

Comment: What exactly is in `myCfile.h`? Was it designed to be used in this way?

Comment: I have some 100+ functions declared in a "myCfile.h", I want to use all the functions in my cpp project, so I need to use extern block, inside I need to provide all the declarations as I mentioned above, so I want to know is there is other simple way to do it ?

Comment: @Durga: No, there isn't. But... what can be simpler that just enclosing everything into `extern "C" {}`??? And it works, unless you have some relatively unorthodox header file. So, again, what does your "not working" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: Not working : if I enclose all the function declarations in side extern block, then no name mangling takes place and code working fine(means that c functions are getting called in my cpp project), but if I enclose only header file instead of all the functions individually then I am getting errors by saying that undefined references.   and I don't want all the functions to be declared in extern block (as there are more function 10++)in my c++ file.        @AndreyT

Comment: Please build and post a minimal example showing what is not working, including the error message. We should be able to reproduce by copy-pasting what is in your question. No vague blablabla not working, be concrete if you want concrete help...

Answer (score 7):

`#include` simply includes the specified header at the location of the `#include`. Whether it's valid depends on what `"myCfile.h"` contains. In particular, including *any* standard library headers in such a context is not valid, and may well break on commonly used implementations.

The usual way to handle this is to make the header itself safe to use from C++. A C-only header might contain

```
#ifndef H_MYCFILE
#define H_MYCFILE

#include <stddef.h>

void mycfunc1(void);
void mycfunc2(int i);
void mycfunc3(size_t s);

#endif
```

Adapting this to make it safe to use from C++:

```
#ifndef H_MYCFILE
#define H_MYCFILE

#include <stddef.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void mycfunc1(void);
void mycfunc2(int i);
void mycfunc3(size_t s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

With such a header, you wouldn't be able to safely put the entire header in an `extern "C"` block. However, that header itself can make sure *not* to put `#include <stddef.h>` in an `extern "C"` block, but still to put all function declarations in a single `extern "C"` block, avoiding having to repeat it for each one.

Comment: Thanks it make sense, but I should not make any changes to .h file, In this case, is there any simple way ??

Comment: @Durga Like I said in a comment on your question and hinted at in this answer: it depends on the header. In general, no. In some specific cases, yes.

Comment: Late to this, but I kept getting "symbol(s) not found for architecture..." in xCode, and finally figured out it was because I was calling C functions from C++ that didn't have 'extern "C"' in their declarations. This solution fixed my problem without having near-duplicate header files included for both C and C++. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing something wrong.

Because

```
extern "C" { myCfunctions.h }
```

should work. See below sample program.

---

Lets go by example code.

ctest1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ctest1(int *i)
{
   printf("This is from ctest1\n"); // output of this is missing
   *i=15;
   return;
}
```

ctest2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ctest2(int *i)
{
   printf("This is from ctest2\n"); // output of this is missing
   *i=100;
   return;
}
```

ctest.h

```
void ctest1(int *);
void ctest2(int *);
```

Now lets make c library from that

```
gcc -Wall -c ctest1.c ctest2.c
ar -cvq libctest.a ctest1.o ctest2.o
```

Now lets make cpp based file which will use this c apis
prog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include"ctest.h"
}
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;
  ctest1(&x);
  std::cout << "Value is" << x;
  ctest2(&x);
  std::cout << "Value is" << x;

}
```

Now lets compile this c++ program with C library

```
g++ prog.cpp libctest.a
```

Output is :
**Value is15Value is100**

Comment: You're making assumptions here about the contents of the header file that are not supported by the information given in the question. You may be right, or you may not be. For some reason, the OP has not been willing to provide more information about the contents of the header file, nor about what specifically is going wrong. However, looking at your answer now, I see that I should make some clarifications in my answer.